# Differential equation higher order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody help me with working out $y'''-4y'=t+\cos t+2e^{-2t}$. I want to solve $y'''-4y'=t$, $y'''-4y'=\cos t$ and $y'''-4y'=2e^{-2t}$ apart. The homogeneous equation I already solved: $y(t)=c_1+c_2e^2t+c_3e^{-2t}$. For the particular solutions I learnt a method called judicious guessing with methods for the cases: 1. $c\ne0$, 2. $c=0$ and $b\ne0$, 3. $c=b=0$. But I don't understand what $a,b,c$ here are (normally: $ay''+by'+cy=0$). Can somebody help me with finding the particular solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a $t$ in the particular solution, but also have a constant in the complimentary, so choose:

$$y_{1p} = t(a + bt)$$

We have $e^{-2t}$ in both the homogeneous and particular, so choose:

$$y_{2p} = c t e^{-2t}$$

We have $\cos t$ in the particular, so choose:

$$y_{3p} = u \cos t + v \sin t$$

Of course, you can just write this as:

$$y_p(t) = t(a + bt)+ cte^{-2t} + u \cos t + v \sin t$$

Take derivatives, substitute and solve for constants.

**Spoiler - Do Not Peek**

> $$y(t) = c_1 + c_2 e^{2t} + c_3 e^{-2t} - \dfrac{1}{8}t^2 + \dfrac{1}{4}te^{-2t} -\dfrac{1}{5}\sin t$$

Comment: @CameronBuie: Sorry, that has also happened to me dozens of times! :-) I also liked your hints, so +1 for that.

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$

Comment: @Amzoti: Oh! sorry if I make any noise here. I do know you 'll perfect in few hours ahead. Good night and remember a good slumber makes your performance better. :-)

Answer (score 3):

For $y'''-4y'=t,$ you should assume that $y$ is a polynomial in $t$, and figure out what such a polynomial would look like.

For $y'''-4y'=\cos t,$ you should assume that $y=\alpha\cos t+\beta\sin t$ for some $\alpha,\beta,$ and see what that looks like.

For $y'''-4y'=2e^{-2t},$ you should assume that $y=p(t)e^{-2t}$ for some polynomial $p$ and see what that looks like.